# How can I change my MAC address?

Tags: mac-address

I want to know that how can I change my MAC address? Is there any software? What do I need?

I need a program, that will automatically change the MAC address, and that can generate random MAC address always.

Comment: What operating system?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you might be able to change it in:

Network and Sharing Center > Change adapter settings > [Properties for the network interface] > Configure > Advanced.

Please note that it is not available on all network interfaces. It really depends on the driver.

Comment: Windows? He's on a MAC! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to do it by setting switches on the network board. 
Look at your hardware and any documentation you have for it.